# Dropdownlistfor is not binding on validation error

Tags: model-view-controller, null, postback, dropdown

I'm new on mvc. I have a view like below (it's just a part of my form);

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoutePageID, (List<SelectListItem>)Model.RoutePagesRoutePageIDList)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoutePageID)
    </div>
```

The items binding dynamically. If i click the save button and send the form with wrong values to get a validation error. I get an error like below;;

**The ViewData item that has the key 'RoutePageID' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.**

Here is my Insert Post controller;

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Insert(CategoryModel _categoryModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //blabla
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Insert", _categoryModel);
        }
    }
```

_categoryModel.RoutePagesRoutePageIDList is null in Controller when i post it. I don't know why? Cause when i first open the Insert page i fill the _categoryModel.RoutePagesRoutePageIDList property then it fills dropdown fine in view. But after send the form to get an error the property is being null? I really don't understand why? I send the same model on return View("Insert", _categoryModel) method. Why is it null? Please help :(

Comment: The error is because `RoutePagesRoutePageIDList` is null when you return the view. You need to repopulate the collection before you return the view (just as you did in the GET method)

Comment: thanks. it works fine now.